# ASP.NET 5 MVC Application on IIS Virtual directory

Tags: wordpress, plesk, asp.net-mvc

We have a WordPress application (PHP) hosted on `www.example.com` and another web application (C# with ASP.NET 4.8. framework) for another workflow.

Second web application (C#) needs to be deployed on `www.example.com/appName`.

We created VirtualDirectory `appName` and published application into that directory, but on `www.example.com/appName` we get 404 response with `error.php` view (404 page for `www.example.com`, not for second app `www.example.com/appName`)

"Authorization" redirect for C# app works because when we request `www.website.com/appName`, URL changes to `www.example.com/appName/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FappName%2F`, meaning that the C# application registers its redirect rules. My guess is that application found "Home" controller and redirected to "Login" controller because of [Authorize] tag (which is desired behavior), but I don't know why the application returns a 404 with `error.php` instead of `/login/index`.

We tested the application on `www.appName.example.com` and it works perfectly but that is not what we need.

Main problem is that server is on hosting and we don't have full access to server (only via Plesk CP so IIS config is limited).

So basically, my question comes down to: how to publish a C# .NET MVC application under WordPress Plesk hosted page?